# Understanding of dispatch_sync and global queues

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I'm studying GCD mechanism and I have couple of questions. I would appreciate if you correct me, if I get material wrong.

**1. question)** As far as i know, GCD have 4 global **concurrent** queues with different priority. For example, when we write `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH`, we get  one of this queues. 
That queues are not empty, some Apple system processes running on them. So, when we add block of code in some of that queue, it could be, for example, n number task in a row, when n is random integer number.

Now, when we add block of code, like

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
      // Heavy calculations
});
```

in `viewDidLoad`, all of `UI` components will be blocked, until:

1. Apple system tasks will be completed (because we add our task last in that queue, and should wait until other system tasks finish)
2. Until our code will complete.

Am I right? I know, we should use `dispatch_async` here, I just wonder how things work.

**2. question)** As far as i know, all of global queues are **concurrent** queues, which mean, that it could manage tasks either through context switch or parallelism. However, when we get to that queue through dispatch_sync, we forced to wait, when all of work will be done. The only thing that is different from serial queues in that case, is order of operations. For example, if serial queue have task 1, task 2, task 3 and task 4, it will do this strictly in order, but concurrent queue could change it order, to complete light-weight operations first.

So, my questions is, why should we ever do **`dispatch_sync`**? In my understanding, **main thread will be blocked** until `dispach_sync` code block will finish.

Comment: Are you actually doing anything related to `UIKit` inside that `dispatch_sync` block? The `UIKit` components will only block if you are referencing them from inside that block in your "Heavy Calculations", and in that case, you are correct. Regarding your second question, this response has a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4607664

Comment: @JaredH suppose my "calculations" take up for 60 sec. I suppose, that until it finish viewDidLoad wont complete, because app will not return to main thread to finish it...

Comment: Well, you probably want to do something other than block the main thread though - you don't want to block `viewDidLoad`. You could do your 60-second calculations on a background thread then present the results and updating your `UIView` on the main thread. While the calculations are being performed, you could show the user some feedback to indicate that a time-consuming calculation is being done.

Comment: @JaredH i understand, i just want to know that i understand concept right :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> GCD have 4 global **concurrent** queues with different priority. For example, when we write `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH`, we get one of this queues. That queues are not empty, some Apple system processes running on them.

At any given time, the queues may be empty or may not. There's no way to know. Yes, the frameworks may add things to those queues just like your code does.

The queue does not run things, though. The queue is a data structure. It holds tasks in order. GCD manages a set of worker threads, creating new ones or having them exit, as necessary. Those worker threads take tasks off of the queues and executes them.

> when we add block of code, like
>
> ```
> dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
>
>       // Heavy calculations
>
>   });
> ```
>
> in `viewDidLoad`, all of `UI` components will be blocked, until: 1 - Apple
>   system tasks will be completed (because we add our task last in that
>   queue, and should wait until other system tasks finish) 2 - Until our
>   code will complete.

As its name implies, `dispatch_sync()` is synchronous. That means it doesn't return until it has completed the work it was asked to do (the block that you passed). Whether you have to wait for any other tasks on the queue or not depends on available system resources. The queue is concurrent, as you noted, so tasks can be pulled off it to run concurrently. If there are enough free CPU cores, GCD may start enough worker threads to run all of the tasks on the queue simultaneously. So, your task does not have to wait for other tasks to complete, it just has to wait for those tasks to have been *started* (popped off of the head of the queue) and for there to be a spare worker thread available.

You would only have to wait for other tasks to complete if all system resources (like CPU cores) are busy.

> As far as i know, all of global queues are **concurrent** queues, which mean, that it could manage tasks either through context switch or parallelism. However, when we get to that queue through dispatch_sync, we forced to wait, when all of work will be done.

No, that's wrong, as I explained above. The only thing that you know has to be completed before `dispatch_sync()` returns is the one task you submitted using it. It does not have to wait for any other tasks on that queue, unless all CPU cores are busy.

> The only thing that is different from serial queues in that case, is order of operations. For example, if serial queue have task 1, task 2, task 3 and task 4, it will do this strictly in order, but concurrent queue could change it order, to complete light-weight operations first.

No. Concurrent queues *start* operations strictly in order, just like serial queues. It's just that a serial queue won't start another operation until the current one, if any, completes. A global concurrent queue will allow all of its operations to start and run simultaneously, up to the available resources. The queues have no way of knowing if an operation is lightweight.

> So, my questions is, why should we ever do dispatch_sync? In my understanding, **main thread will be blocked** until `dispach_sync` code block will finish.

Concurrency and synchronous behavior are two separate concepts. Synchronous vs. asynchronous determines the behavior of the **caller**. It determines if the caller is allowed to proceed before the work is done.

Concurrent vs. serial determines how the tasks which were submitted run. A concurrent queue allows the tasks to run concurrently with one another. A serial queue only allows one of its tasks to run at a time.

It can make sense to call `dispatch_sync()` from the main thread, but you have to be careful. It can be necessary, for example, when using a serial queue to synchronize access to a data structure which is shared by multiple threads. The general rule is that you need to avoid blocking the main thread for long periods. It's OK to block it if you have good reason to believe that it will be for very short periods that the user won't be able to perceive.

You definitely don't want to use `dispatch_sync()` from the main thread for "Heavy calculations", as you put it.

In general, you use `dispatch_sync()` when you need the task to be complete before you can go on. Often, you can restructure your code to instead use `dispatch_async()` and put the subsequent code into the task as a continuation step (or completion handler). But you can't always do that.

Comment: all right, if we just assume we have a system with no hyperthreading and single core, my example will block UI until it finish? And, how many threads will can run at the same time? Is there any way to determine? Thank you for best answer, by the way, but now it hard for me to get this concept in my head, because behavior many conditions for now is unknown for me... :)

Comment: Your example will always block the UI until your task finishes because that's the nature of `dispatch_sync()`. It doesn't matter how many cores. The number of cores affects whether your task can start immediately if there are also other tasks running. There's no way to know how many threads there are at one time. GCD is not the only thing which uses threads. Anyway, GCD can sometimes start more threads than there are cores because some of the threads it started may block (waiting for I/O, for example) leaving cores temporarily idle. After the threads unblock, the cores will be overbooked.

Comment: im sorry, you mean that UI (main thread) will be blocked in ANY CASE when we use dispatch_sync?

Comment: Of course, that is what sync means. BTW: Every statement in your code will block the thread it is running in including `int a = 1+2;`. And if it is the main thread, it block the UI. The trick is to have no blockers that are long running.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban, you specifically wrote that the task you're submitting using `dispatch_sync()` is "Heavy calculations", which I take to mean it will take a long time. Whenever you submit a task using `dispatch_sync()`, the caller waits until that task completes. So, if you submit a task which takes a long time from the main thread using `dispatch_sync()`, you will block the main thread for that long time, which is bad.

Comment: @KenThomases thanks, now i understand all that you saying. Its bad, but its good for understanding.